# Oracle SQL Trigger error: ORA-00933

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, ora-00933

So I'm trying to create a trigger that alters a records timestamp, I have this so far

```
    create or replace TRIGGER job_date_set
      AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF start_date, closing_date ON jobs
      FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF UPDATING THEN
        CASE
          WHEN :OLD.closing_date != :NEW.closing_date THEN 
            UPDATE jobs
            SET closing_date = to_date(to_date(:NEW.closing_date,'DD/MON/YYYY')||' 23:59:59','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            WHERE :OLD.job_id = job_id;
          WHEN :OLD.start_date != :NEW.start_date THEN 
            UPDATE jobs
            SET start_date = to_date(to_date(:NEW.start_date,'DD/MON/YYYY') ||' 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            WHERE :OLD.job_id = job_id;
        END CASE;
      END IF;
      IF INSERTING THEN
        UPDATE jobs
        SET closing_date = to_date(to_date(:NEW.closing_date,'DD/MON/YYYY') ||' 23:59:59','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        SET start_date = to_date(to_date(:NEW.start_date,'DD/MON/YYYY')||' 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        WHERE :OLD.job_id = job_id;   
      END IF;
    END;
```

Here is the description of the errors:
Compilation failed, line 17 (16:54:27) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly endedCompilation failed, line 15 (16:54:27) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

By the sounds of it, it doesn't think my if statement has been closed properly, but I have no idea where I've gone wrong

Comment: It looks like jobs.closing_date and jobs.start_date are `date` columns. If so, your `to_date(to_date(` should be `to_date(to_char(` - you want to convert the date into a character string in DD/MON/YYYY format in order to append `' 23:59:59'` to it and convert it back to a date. (It might be simpler to `trunc` it, add 1 and subtract `interval '1' second`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    UPDATE jobs
    SET closing_date = to_date(to_date(:NEW.closing_date,'DD/MON/YYYY') ||' 23:59:59','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    SET start_date = to_date(to_date(:NEW.start_date,'DD/MON/YYYY')||' 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHERE :OLD.job_id = job_id;
```

it's:

```
    UPDATE jobs
    SET closing_date = to_date(to_date(:NEW.closing_date,'DD/MON/YYYY') ||' 23:59:59','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
        start_date = to_date(to_date(:NEW.start_date,'DD/MON/YYYY')||' 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    WHERE :OLD.job_id = job_id;
```

I.e. there is a comma instead of the second *SET* keyword.

Answer (score 1):

When you are modifying the table the trigger is defined on, you want a *before* update trigger.  So, something like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER job_date_set
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF start_date, closing_date ON jobs
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING THEN
    CASE
      WHEN :OLD.closing_date <> :NEW.closing_date THEN 
        SELECT to_date(to_date(:NEW.closing_date,'DD/MON/YYYY')||' 23:59:59','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        INTO :NEW.closing_date
        FROM dual;
      WHEN :OLD.start_date <> :NEW.start_date THEN 
        SELECT to_date(to_date(:NEW.start_date,'DD/MON/YYYY') ||' 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        INTO :NEW.start_date
        FROM dual;
    END CASE;
  END IF;
  IF INSERTING THEN
    SELECT to_date(to_date(:NEW.closing_date,'DD/MON/YYYY') ||' 23:59:59','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
           to_date(to_date(:NEW.start_date,'DD/MON/YYYY')||' 00:00:00','DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    INTO :NEW.closing_date, :NEW.start_date;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I think My plan was to have a trigger before insert that inserts an auto increment, so I would have to edit the date after, do you think It would be better to incorporate this code into that trigger or have two separate triggers doing two different tasks?